# Germs of holomorphic functions and invariant functions

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, invariant-theory

Consider a complex vector space $V \cong {\mathbb C}^n$. Consider the ring of germs of holomorphic functions ${\mathcal O}_0 (V)$ at $0\in V$. We know that this ring is Noetherian.

Now consider a finite group $G$ acting linearly on $V$ and consider the subring of $G$-invariant germs, denoted by
$${\mathcal O}_0 (V)^G.$$
Consider another $G$-representation $W$ and the set of germs of $G$-equivariant holomorphic maps $f: V \to W$ at $0\in V$, denoted by ${\rm Map}_0 (V, W)^G$. This is a module over ${\mathcal O}_0 (V)^G$.

**Question**: is ${\rm Map}_0(V, W)^G$ finitely generated over ${\mathcal O}_0(V)^G$? Can we take generators to be polynomial maps?

Background: we know that for the ring of invariant polynomial maps and the module of equivariant polynomial maps, the answer is yes (see the [Mathoverflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/223785/equivariant-polynomial-maps)) It is easy to see that the version for formal power series is also true.

Comment: Is the ring $\mathcal{O}_0(V)$ a finite type $\mathbf{C}$-algebra? I'm a bit rusty.

Comment: The local ring $\mathcal{O}_0(V)^G$ is an algebra over $\mathbb{C}[V^G]$, the ring $\mathbb{C}[V]$ is a finite module over $\mathbb{C}[V^G]$, and thus the module $\mathcal{O}_0(V) = \mathbb{C}[V]\otimes_{\mathbb{C}[V]}\mathcal{O}_0(V)^G$ is a finite module over $\mathcal{O}_0(V)^G$.  Since $\text{Poly}_0(V,W)$ is a finite (free) module over $\mathbb{C}[V]$, also $\text{Map}_0(V,W)=\text{Poly}_0(V,W)\otimes_{\mathbb{C}[V]}\mathcal{O}_0(V)$ is a finite (free) module over $\mathcal{O}_0(V)$, and thus also a finite module over $\mathcal{O}_0(V)^G$.

Comment: . . . Since $\mathcal{O}_0(V)^G=\mathcal{O}_0(V/G)$ is Noetherian, also the $\mathcal{O}_0(V)^G$ submodule $\text{Map}_0(V,W)^G$ of the finitely generated $\mathcal{O}_0(V)^G$ module $\text{Map}_0(V,W)$ is a finitely generated $\mathcal{O}_0(V)^G$-module. (I forgot to add that step to the previous comment.)